# Border around r dygraphs plot

Tags: r, dygraphs

I would like to have a border around my entire dygraphs plot, encompassing the title, axis labels, legend, etc.  After searching, I think I should be able to use the underlayCallback option to do this, but I cannot find an example, and am very new to dygraphs.  Can anyone point me to an example I've missed, or provide me with a bit of general code to draw the border? I have some plots drawn with ggplot2 (non-interactive), and want my dygraphs to look similar.  Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to others (not necessarily the folks who can help you) if you provide working source code to generate a dygraph plot (even a basic one). That way even folks who do help you do not have to generate one from scratch. Here's [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on providing reproducible examples.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you.  I usually try to do this, but thought this was probably a SUPER basic question that someone more "skilled in the art" would just have handy.

Comment: Roger that. I additionally point it out since some folks use answering questions to learn how to code in R (which is one reason I edit questions: to make it easier for them copy/paste working code). I do agree that you would have only ended up pasting 3 lines of code and, perhaps, an image ;-)

Comment: @hrbrmstr It's a good point about providing a good example for others who are searching.  Will do in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use CSS for this:

```
library(dygraphs)

lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
writeLines("div[id^='htmlwidget_container'] { border:1px solid black; padding:10px}", 
           "my.css")
dygraph(lungDeaths, main="Title", xlab="X", ylab="Y") %>% 
  dyCSS("my.css") %>% 
  dyCallbacks(underlayCallback=JS("function(ctx, area, dygraph) {
                         ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                         ctx.strokeRect(area.x, area.y, area.w, area.h);
                     }"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution - works like a champ!  I did +1 your answer, but don't have enough reputation points for it to show up.  Two additional questions:  (1)  I didn't see "border" as a dygraphs CSS option, or I would have tried it.  Did I miss it someplace, or...?  (2)  I didn't even know I could write lines to my CSS that way.  However, it seems to overwrite everything else in there :(  Anything I can do to avoid that?  Thanks again!

Comment: ah, if you have an existing CSS file, just add that CSS rule to it. it's targeting the div with standard CSS styling rules (`border` is a property of many DOM objects).

Comment: Also...what about closing in the border around the graph itself (adding on to the x and y axes to create a complete box?)  Or - do I need to create a separate question for this?

Comment: No, that's a gd q. Unfortunately, those aren't `<div>` elements with a simple half-completed border. The X & Y axes are made with `d3.svg.axis()`, so they are actually SVG lines. You'd have to do some serious post-dygraph SVG surgery to add the top and right lines in.

Comment: I'm glad I asked, instead of spending countless hours searching!  I will just try to color the background grey instead - I think I saw some references for that.  Thank you again for all your help, and the pointers.  Especially so quickly!

Comment: Actually, I totally mis-spoke. I had NVD3 on the brain (I live in D3-land alot these days). It's even "worse" than SVG since dygraphs is `<canvas>`-based, do you'd end up having to do the callback for that. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/280/ (I also updated the answer with the example). You may need to poke around for how to tweak the legend so it doesn't overwrite the border.